# How do I get the most recent processdate in a group?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm wanting to get the most recent entry per month using acct.processdate. I've tried using the MAX() function, but it doesn't help since I am using group by. How do I go about doing this?

```
DECLARE @StartDate AS INT
        , @EndDate AS int

SET @StartDate = '20190131'
SET @EndDate = '20191130'

SELECT count(*) as [Account Count]
        , datename(MONTH, CAST(CAST(ProcessDate AS VARCHAR(10)) AS SMALLDATETIME)) AS [Month Name]
        , (CAST(CAST(acct.ProcessDate AS VARCHAR(10)) AS SMALLDATETIME)) AS [Process Date]

from ARCUSYM000.dbo.ACCOUNT acct

where acct.CLOSEDATE is null AND 
 (acct.ProcessDate >= @StartDate
    AND acct.ProcessDate <= @EndDate)
GROUP BY acct.ProcessDate
ORDER BY (CAST(CAST(acct.ProcessDate AS VARCHAR(10)) AS SMALLDATETIME)) desc
```

This is my current result:

[image]

This is my desired result:

[image]

New result with the CTE:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried with Row_Number()?

Comment: This feels like a data issues. What does your raw data look like? Are there multiple values of `acct.ProcessDate` in any months other than November?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put your result in a  cte and use not exists function

```
DECLARE @StartDate AS INT
        , @EndDate AS int

SET @StartDate = '20190131'
SET @EndDate = '20191130'

;with cte as
(
SELECT count(*) as [Account Count]
        , datename(MONTH, CAST(CAST(ProcessDate AS VARCHAR(10)) AS SMALLDATETIME)) AS [Month Name]
        , (CAST(CAST(acct.ProcessDate AS VARCHAR(10)) AS SMALLDATETIME)) AS [Process Date]

from ARCUSYM000.dbo.ACCOUNT acct

where acct.CLOSEDATE is null AND 
 (acct.ProcessDate >= @StartDate
    AND acct.ProcessDate <= @EndDate)
GROUP BY acct.ProcessDate
)
select * from cte a
where not exists(select 1 from cte b where a.[Month Name] = b.[Month Name] and 
a.[Process Date] < b.[Process Date] )
```

Comment: I'm getting almost the same result from this.

Comment: You should get exactly the right result if you want unique of [Account Count] with the latest [Process Date]

Comment: If something is off let me know what

Comment: I've put the result of the CTE in the question. I'm not sure why it's giving me so many for November still.

Comment: Ok, Changed the unique to the MonName, it should be ok now. Review my answer again

Comment: Do you know if it would be possible to have both January of 2019 and 2020 in this result? If I have my start date as '20190101' and my end date as '20200210', it will only give me March of 2019 to February of 2020.

Comment: Its possible, in your subquery you add the year the way you added [Month Name] and in my query where you have a.[Month Name] = b.[Month Name], you add "and a.[Year] = b.[Year]"

Answer (score 0):

The following should work by using CTE. The concept is to group by month and max(date), and lastly join the table to itself. The rows of the group by would act as a composite key to be used for the join.

Be sure to declare your startdate and enddate variables as date types, otherwise the BETWEEN function will fail.
Also note that because the group by only works on the month name, including data for more than a year back can lead to unexpected results. In that case I would use the YEAR() function to add a year column that I can include in the group by clause.

```
DECLARE @StartDate AS date -- Define these as dates
       , @EndDate AS date

SET @StartDate = '20190131'
SET @EndDate = '20191130'


;WITH accountCounts AS -- Original Data
(
    SELECT count(*) as [Account Count]
    , datename(MONTH, CAST(CAST(ProcessDate AS VARCHAR(10)) AS SMALLDATETIME)) AS [Month Name]
    , (CAST(CAST(acct.ProcessDate AS VARCHAR(10)) AS SMALLDATETIME)) AS [Process Date]
    FROM ARCUSYM000.dbo.ACCOUNT acct
),
accountCountsDateFiltered AS -- Filtered on date 
(
        SELECT * FROM accountCounts
        WHERE [Process Date] BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
),
accountCountGrouped AS -- Grouped without the account count
(
    SELECT AC.[Month Name], MAX(AC.[Process Date]) as [Process Date] 
    FROM accountCountsDateFiltered AC
    GROUP BY [Month Name] --Note: Going back another year may group this years Month with last years
)
--  Adds account count column by joining to itself on both columns.
SELECT DF.[Account Count], DF.[Month Name], DF.[Process Date] 
FROM accountCountGrouped AG 
JOIN accountCountsDateFiltered DF ON DF.[Month Name] = AG.[Month Name] AND DF.[Process Date] = AG.[Process Date]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ROW_NUMBER() to find individual rows with a sub-query, and choose the latest (/earliest) row.

```
declare @ARCUSYM000_dbo_ACCOUNT table
        (ProcessDate    datetime,
        CLOSEDATE       datetime)

insert  @ARCUSYM000_dbo_ACCOUNT
values  ('20190201', '20190228'),
        ('20190201', null),
        ('20190201', null),
        ('20190202', null),
        ('20190202', null),
        ('20190202', '20190228'),
        ('20190202', null),
        ('20190203', null),
        ('20190203', null),
        ('20190203', null),
        ('20190204', null),
        ('20190204', null),
        ('20190204', null),
        ('20190204', '20190228'),
        ('20190301', '20190331'),
        ('20190302', null),
        ('20190303', null),
        ('20190303', '20190331'),
        ('20190303', null),
        ('20190304', null),
        ('20190305', null),
        ('20190305', '20190331'),
        ('20190305', null),
        ('20190305', '20190331'),
        ('20190305', null),
        ('20190305', '20190331'),
        ('20190305', null),
        ('20190401', null)

-- select * from @ARCUSYM000_dbo_ACCOUNT

DECLARE @StartDate date
        , @EndDate date

SET @StartDate = '20190131'
SET @EndDate = '20191130'

SELECT      latest_account_process.[Account Count]
            ,latest_account_process.[Month Name]
            ,latest_account_process.[Process Date]
FROM        (
            SELECT  COUNT(*)                                                                                        AS [Account Count]
                    ,DATENAME(MONTH,ProcessDate)                                                                    AS [Month Name]
                    ,acct.ProcessDate                                                                               AS [Process Date]
                    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY DATENAME(MONTH,ProcessDate) ORDER BY acct.ProcessDate DESC)     AS rownum
            FROM    @ARCUSYM000_dbo_ACCOUNT acct
            WHERE   acct.CLOSEDATE is null 
            AND     acct.ProcessDate >= @StartDate
            AND     acct.ProcessDate <= @EndDate
            GROUP BY acct.ProcessDate
            ) latest_account_process
WHERE       latest_account_process.rownum = 1
ORDER BY    latest_account_process.[Process Date] DESC
```

The "PARTITION BY" would be the month you with to partition the results by, and the "ORDER BY" used to select the latest ProcessDate as row 1, then you can filter the results of the sub-query in your main SELECT statement.

I've simplified your SQL slightly as I don't know the underlying table schema, but hope the example includes enough to help you.